# Forces in a hydraulic lift

Tags: fluid-statics

[image]

My answer states that the force applied is the same for 1 and 3 but less than the one in 2. I understand why 2 is greater than 1 but do not understand why 1 and 3 are the same when 3 has double the weight. Could someone explain this please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is required of the external force is to maintain the pressure in the fluid. In picture one, the force $F_1$ (magnitude) on area A maintains a pressure in the fluid (at the same height) to put the piston and its 600 N weight in equilibrium on a 2A area. As long as that pressure is maintained (by having $F_1$ on A), the fluid will have the same pressure everywhere at that height, so you could have 3 or 4 areas of 2A that would support the 600 N weights.

If the areas at the 600 N weights in figure 3 were less than 2A, $F_3$ would need to be larger because the pressure in the fluid would need to be higher.

Keep in mind: the forces, $F_1,~ F_2,~ F_3$, on the left area A are applied to the piston which interacts with the fluid resulting in a pressure. Those forces are Not applied to the weights on the right. The lifting force on the right comes from the pressure of the fluid on the support pistons.